# Logloss metric in Fastai

Tags: pytorch, metrics, fast-ai

i'm doing a competition in zindi plateform which they are using The evaluation metric for this challenge as Log Loss.

so i'm working with fastai library and i want the metric log loss .. i didn't find LogLoss as metric in this library ! 
i tried some codes like the function provided by sklearn `from sklearn.metrics import log_loss` but i didn't work
the link of the competition : https://zindi.africa/competitions/basic-needs-basic-rights-kenya-tech4mentalhealth

Comment: I don't know about FastAI specifically, but PyTorch has the negative log likelihood loss [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) and [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), depending on whether you already have log probabilities or not.

Answer (score 2):

if needed as a metric (typically mostly used as a loss) you should be able to use cross_entropy function from pytorch:

> import torch.nn.functional as F
>
> metrics=[F.cross_entropy,(plus other metrics if needed)]
>
> model= cnn_learner(data, model, metrics=metrics,...)